# COM IContextMenu::InvokeCommand - matching LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO::lpVerb to item

Tags: c++, com, contextmenu, shell-extensions

I have created a shell extension for windows with `COM`, however I seem to fail to properly match the ids of items I add in the overload of `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu` with what I receive in the overload of `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`. In my code I use `InsertMenu` and `InsertMenuItem` (as far as I understood they do the same, but the latter has some more features?). However I'm not sure which arguments passed to `InsertMenu`/`InsertMenuItem` correspond to what I must be looking for in `LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO::lpVerb`. I need some way to easily know that when I add items `x`, `y`, `z` to a context menu, I can then know exactly which one of `x`, `y` or `z` has been clicked.

EDIT: It seems that the verb equals the number from top to bottom of the item in the current menu/submenu. However I have two sub-menus each with `x` amount of items, so they have the same IDs of 1,2,3. How do I set custom IDs or something?

Comment: Don't ask for a manual, it has been written already.  Show your code.

Comment: Where has it been written?

Comment: @HansPassant I can't seem to find a manual that explains this very well, there is only an online tutorial that adds just a single verb and you always know it's the one

Comment: Even if you add only one menu item shell can call your InvokeCommand with external ID. So you MUST check command ID even in case of single menu item.

Comment: I suspect that `lpVerb` you are getting may be `MAKEINTRESOURCE(yourCommandId)`. Check with `IS_INTRESOURCE`. Alternatively, it could be whatever verb you associated with the command via your implementation of `IContextMenu::GetCommandString(GCS_VERB{A|W})`

Comment: This is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127443.aspx . In this doc, a custom command 'IDM_DISPLAY' is fully implemented as an example.

Comment: @shortage_radeon Please show your `QueryContextMenu` and your `InvokeCommand` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should define an enum that holds the command IDs for your menu items, e.g.

```
enum {
    CMDID_FIRST = 0,

    CMDID_DOSOMETHING = CMDID_FIRST,
    CMDID_DOSOMETHINGELSE,

    CMDID_LAST,
};
```

These ID values need to start from 0.

In your `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu` implementation:

- when you add your menu items you need to give each of them an ID by setting the `MIIM_ID` flag in the `MENUITEMINFO.fMask` field, and setting the `MENUITEMINFO.wID` value.
- give each of your menu items an ID derived from its command ID as defined above, **plus** the value of *idCmdFirst* which is passed into `QueryContextMenu`. E.g. the "Do Something" menu item would have `MENUITEMINFO.wID` set to `idCmdFirst + CMDID_DOSOMETHING`, and "Do Something Else" would have `MENUITEMINFO.wID` set to `idCmdFirst + CMDID_DOSOMETHINGELSE`.
- the return value from `QueryContextMenu` needs to be `MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS, FACILITY_NULL, x)` where *x* is the ID of the highest-numbered item you added plus 1 (alternatively, if all items were sequentially numbered, the total number of items). Basically, you're telling the host which menu item ID values are now in use so that no other context menu extensions add items that clash with yours. In the above example, you'd return `MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS, FACILITY_NULL, CMDID_LAST)`.

In `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`:

- test if `lpVerb` (or `lpVerbW`) is an integer value using the `IS_INTRESOURCE` macro.
- if so, the command ID can be found in the low word. E.g, if the user selected "Do Something Else", you would find that `LOWORD(lpVerb) == CMDID_DOSOMETHINGELSE`.

Comment: Do you know why there's a certain asymmetry between `QueryContextMenu` and `InvokeCommand`, in that you add the `idCmdFirst` offset in the first method, and yet you don't subtract it in the second?

Comment: @loop123123 I'm guessing that the host subtracts the value when invoking your command as a convenience to you. Otherwise, you'd need to store `idCmdFirst` somewhere (since it's not passed as part of the invoke). When adding you need to do the maths because you're the one actually creating the menu item, and the ID is an integral part of the menu item.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  One thing I'd recommend adding is that if you don't process the command in `InvokeCommand`, you need to return `E_FAIL`.  Otherwise, you totally mess up other context menu commands.  I just learned that the hard way.

Comment: @loop123123 Yes this is in the documentation. *If the verb, specified either by a canonical verb name or the command ID is not recognized by the context menu handler, it must return a failure (E_FAIL) so that the verb can be passed on to other context menu handlers that might implement it.*

Comment: Would you be willing to provide any feedback on my approach here?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62374937/13366655